# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone tell me why the following code produces this error?

```
In [130]: [(str(i), len(list(set(pd.unique(myData[i]))))) for i in list(myData.columns)]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-130-6f3c233b81d6>", line 1, in <module>
    [(str(i), len(list(set(pd.unique(myData[i]))))) for i in list(myData.columns)]

  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 368, in unique
    uniques = table.unique(values)

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1567, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: I realize that this was a dumb question and it has been downvoted at least once, should I delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem, the reason you're running into this is because you have `dict` type in your pandas dataframe cells.

You can put `dict` type in your dataframe but `pd.unique()` fails due to it tries to hash the elements to determine which one is unique, and `dict` is unhashable.

Also, the `set` in your list comprehension is not necessary as `pd.unique` already take cares of that.

I reproduced the same problem with the exact same stack trace by having pandas read a list of list, of which some elements were dictionary. The read was successful but then it failed. A solution may be to print the dict if there are only a few or pre-process the data before making it a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

As mention in some of the answers, your dataframe probably contains a dict. You can convert values into string type before using unique as shown below:

```
[(str(i), len(my_data[i].astype(str).unique())) for i in list(my_data.columns)]
```